# Is Internet Explorer needed for anything in Win10? (Can I remove it?)

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

Look into various solutions for automating new installs of W10, I was surprised to learn that *Internet Explorer* (1995!) was also installed with any new W10 distribution.

Q: **Is this used by anything critical in the OS or can I remove it?**

---

Googling gave somewhat contradicting info:

- [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Windows-10-have-Internet-Explorer-and-Microsoft-Edge-Why-are-they-still-continuing-with-Explorer?share=1)
- [the Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2019/2/8/18216767/microsoft-internet-explorer-warning-compatibility-solution)

Answer (score 1):

IE is not needed and has even become an optional feature in Windows 10.
However, some old legacy products may still launch it to display their
website.

There are two ways to uninstall it:

**Control Panel Program and Features**

- Open *Control Panel > Program and Features > Turn Windows features on or off*
- Clear the "Internet Explorer 11" option
- Click OK
- Click Yes if asked
- Click Restart now.

**Using PowerShell**

- Run PowerShell as administrator
- Enter the following command:

  ```
    Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 –Online
  ```
- Type Y and press Enter to confirm
- Your device will restart to complete the process.

Comment: Hi @harrymc, welcome to SE-SU! Thanks for useful answer, but I already know how to disable it, and I'm trying to decide whether or not I can/should do it. Is there a way to find out if I have/need any such *legacy products*?

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 still ships with Internet Explorer 11 as a legacy feature to support sites using old web technologies. You will still need it if you are running legacy content and web apps.

So it is not recommend to remove IE, just keep it installed and available.